# is the LHS total derivative?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

$$\frac{\partial p(z(t), t)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial p(z(t), t)}{\partial z(t)} \frac{\partial z(t)}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial p(z(t), t)}{\partial t}$$

Shouldn't the LHS be total derivative of p wrt to t?
(source page 14 of [Neural ODE Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.07366v5.pdf))

Comment: Yes. That notation is very confusing because the LHS equals the last term on the RHS which is not the case.